# Can the number of sign changes in a sequence of determinants tell us how many negative eigenvalues a symmetric matrix has?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

From notes, I've gathered that given a symmetric matrix, the number of sign changes in its **characteristic polynomial** is equal to the number of **positive** eigenvalues of $A$.

---

**Proof:** Let $p(x)$ be a real polynomial whose roots are all real. By Descarte’s rule,
the number $\sigma$ of positive eigenvalues is bounded by the number of sign changes in $p(x)$. Similarly, the number $\sigma'$ of negative eigenvalues is bounded by the number of sign changes in $p(−x)$. Hence the total number of positive and negative eigenvalues is bounded by $\sigma+\sigma'$ Now  $\sigma + \sigma' \leq n$ and the fact that all eigenvalues of a symmetric real matrix are real imply that the bound of Descarte’s rule of signs holds with equality.

---

How can I use this proof to show that the sign changes in a **certain sequence of determinants** tells us how many **negative** eigenvalues $A$ has?

Comment: Hint: The number of negative eigenvalues of $A$ is the number of positive eigenvalues of $-A$.

Comment: How can anyone possibly answer this without knowing what that sequence of determinants is?

Comment: I'm unclear on this sequence as well, the characteristic polynomial is itself a determinant, so the proof above shows that the sign changes in an single evaluated determinant bounds the number of positive eigenvalues of $A$ and one can get the bound of the negative eigenvalues by $p(-t)$. I don't know where to take it from there.

Comment: What if we look at the number of sign changes in
the sequence of determinants of the upper left sub-matrices (preferrably after first having converted the matrix to a similar tri-diagonal matrix)

Comment: Isn't it true that if the upper-left matrices of $A$ a symmetric matrix all have positive determinants then the eigenvalues of $A$ are all positive as well?

Comment: @logic yes, this is true. And in fact, the sign changes count the number of negative eigenvalues.  However, it is not clear how this would be derived from the statement you started with.

Comment: Then isn't it true that the sign changes in the sequences of the determinants of the upper-left matrices of $A$ count the number of negative eigenvalues. So we just need to formalize this proof and we're done. My original post with the characteristic polynomial was me sort of "fishing" for this "sequence of determinants"

Comment: I'll rephrase the question

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as this one, which you asked earlier: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989836/number-of-positive-negative-eigenvalues-and-the-number-of-sign-changes-in-the-d/989952#989952

Comment: descartes' ruke of sign says that the number of positive roots of the characteristic polynomial is bounded above by the number of changes of sign of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. the coefficients of the char poly is the sum of the principal minors of various order.

Answer (score 3):

I think that there are two true statements here:

(1) If $A$ is an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix, and $A_k$ denotes its $k \times k$ upper left corner, then the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$ is the number of sign changes in the sequence $(1, \det A_1, \det A_2, \ldots, \det A_n)$.

(2) If $\det (A+z \mathrm{Id}) = a_0 + a_1 z + \cdots + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + z^n$, then the number of negative eigenvalues of $A$ is the number of sign changes in the sequence $(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}, 1)$.

The first statement is proved in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989836); the second is proved by Descartes as you say; I don't think there is any easy way to get from one to the other.

---

I've been thinking about this more, and there is a relation between the two questions. Let $\bigwedge\nolimits^k A$ be the $\binom{n}{k} \times \binom{n}{k}$ matrix describing the action of $A$ on $\bigwedge\nolimits^k \mathbb{R}^n$. Both the determinant of $A_k$ and the $k$-th coefficient of the characteristic polynomial are linear functions of $\bigwedge\nolimits^k A$. It would be neat to have some general theorem about sequences $f_1$, $f_2$, ..., $f_n$ where $f_k$ is a linear functional on $\mathrm{End}(\bigwedge\nolimits^k \mathbb{R}^n)$ so that the sign changes of $f_k(\bigwedge\nolimits^k A)$ compute signature.